# What is the probability that a fair coin results in heads in $4$ out of $5$ tosses?

Tags: probability

A true-false exam has $5$ questions.

Andy is completely ignorant and so he tosses a fair coin to decide his answer to each question.

What is the probability that he scores at least $4$ correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let $H = \text{true}$, and $T = \text{false}$, then $P(x \geq 4) = P(4) + P(5) = \binom{5}{4}0.5^5 + 0.5^5 = 0.1875$